# Process groups of file pairs from multiple directories

Tags: arrays, bash, file-processing

I have some `.txt` files in `dir1`:

```
file_name_FOO31101.txt
file_name_FOO31102.txt
file_name_FOO31103.txt
file_name_FOO31104.txt
```

and some related `foo.txt` files in `dir2`:

```
file_name_FOO31101_foo.txt
file_name_FOO31102_foo.txt
file_name_FOO31103_foo.txt
file_name_FOO31104_foo.txt
```

I ultimately want to be able to call a program for pairs of files such that:

**Iteration 1**

```
program_call \
    --txt file_name_FOO31101.txt,file_name_FOO31102.txt \
    --foo file_name_FOO31101_foo.txt,file_name_FOO31102_foo.txt \
    --bar file_name_FOO31101_bar.txt,file_name_FOO31102_bar.txt
```

**Iteration 2**

```
program_call \
        --txt file_name_FOO31103.txt,file_name_FOO31104.txt \
        --foo file_name_FOO31103_foo.txt,file_name_FOO31104_foo.txt \
        --bar file_name_FOO31103_bar.txt,file_name_FOO31104_bar.txt
```

I.e.
`file_name_FOO31101.txt,file_name_FOO31102.txt`
`file_name_FOO31103.txt,file_name_FOO31104.txt`
but **not**
`file_name_FOO31102.txt,file_name_FOO31103.txt`

An answer from a [question I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618084/process-files-in-pairs) got me started:

```
#!/bin/bash

txt_files=/path/to/txt
foo_files=/path/to/foo/files

set -- "$txt_files"/*.txt

[[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]] || { echo "No .txt files found in $txt_files" >&2; exit 1; }

# $# = number of command line arguments passed to the script
while (( $# > 1 )); do

  stem=$(basename "${1}" )
  output_base=$(echo $stem | cut -d '_' -f 1,2,3) # split on '_' and save ID  

  echo "-> Processing pairs of txt files : $1,$2"

  # Add files to array
  txt1+=($1)
  txt2+=($2)

  shift; shift

done

(( $# )) && echo "Left over file $1 still exists"
```

And then (not knowing a better way of doing this) I repeat the same loop for the `foo` files in `dir2`:

```
set -- "$foo_files"/*_foo.txt

[[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]] || { echo "No foo.txt files found in $foo_files" >&2; exit 1; }

# $# = number of command line arguments passed to the script
while (( $# > 1 )); do

  stem=$(basename "${1}" )
  output_base=$(echo $stem | cut -d '_' -f 1,2,3) # split on '_' and save ID

  # Add files to array
  foo1+=($1)
  foo2+=($2)

  echo "-> Processing pairs of foo.txt files : $1,$2"

  shift; shift

done

(( $# )) && echo "Left over file $1 still exists"
```

And then iterate over one of the arrays (all must be the same length) and call program:

```
# Seeing as all arrays must be the same length, loop over one and print out corresponding values for others 
for ((i=0;i<${#txt1[@]};++i)); do
    printf "program_call --txt %s,%s --foo %s,%s\n" "${txt1[i]}" "${txt2[i]}" "${foo1[i]}" "${foo2[i]}" 
done
```

Which seems to basically work, printing:

```
program_call --txt /path/to/txt/file_name_FOO31101.txt,/path/to/txt/file_name_FOO31102.txt --foo /path/to/foo/files/file_name_FOO31101_foo.txt,/path/to/foo/files/file_name_FOO31102_foo.txt
program_call --txt /path/to/txt/file_name_FOO31103.txt,/path/to/txt/file_name_FOO31104.txt --foo /path/to/foo/files/file_name_FOO31103_foo.txt,/path/to/foo/files/file_name_FOO31104_foo.txt
```

However, I suspect that using the same while loop for all different dirs is a poor way of achieving this result, particularly if I want to call add more options in my program call (e.g. `file_name_FOO31101_bar.txt` ...).

**Is this a sensible way of going about this?**

Comment: Is there a question? I see things working well

Answer (score 0):

you intuition is correct: there are faster ways than `bash` loops and arrays.

here's how to list and sort the files in both directories:

```
find txt foo -type f -name "*.txt" | sort -t'/' -k2,2
```

output:

```
txt/a_0001.txt
foo/a_0001_foo.txt
txt/a_0002.txt
foo/a_0002_foo.txt
txt/a_0003.txt
foo/a_0003_foo.txt
txt/a_0004.txt
foo/a_0004_foo.txt
...
```

next, assuming that there are no extra or missing files in either of the directories, you can get 4/line with `awk`:

```
find txt foo -type f -name "*.txt" | sort -t'/' -k2,2 |
  awk '{printf $1" "; if(NR%4==0)printf "\n"}'
```

output:

```
txt/a_0001.txt foo/a_0001_foo.txt txt/a_0002.txt foo/a_0002_foo.txt 
txt/a_0003.txt foo/a_0003_foo.txt txt/a_0004.txt foo/a_0004_foo.txt 
txt/a_0005.txt foo/a_0005_foo.txt txt/a_0006.txt foo/a_0006_foo.txt 
...
```

next, you could use another `awk` to re-order them and make the command strings:

```
find txt foo -type f -name "*.txt" | sort -t'/' -k2,2 |
  awk '{printf $1" "; if(NR%4==0)printf "\n"}' |
  awk '{print "program_call --txt "$1","$3" --foo "$2","$4}'
```

output:

```
program_call --txt txt/a_0001.txt,txt/a_0002.txt --foo foo/a_0001_foo.txt,foo/a_0002_foo.txt
program_call --txt txt/a_0003.txt,txt/a_0004.txt --foo foo/a_0003_foo.txt,foo/a_0004_foo.txt
...
```

benchmark to make 500 command strings from 2000 files with fugu's code vs `find|sort|awk|awk`:

```
bash loops & arrays    10.070s
find|sort|awk|awk       0.019s
```

that's over 500x as fast :)

you can also save time by using pipes instead of loops to run the command strings:

```
find txt foo -type f -name "*.txt" | ... | sh
```

and usually even more time by piping commands instead to GNU `parallel`:

```
find txt foo -type f -name "*.txt" | ... | parallel
```

(you may have to install `parallel` if it's not already on your system.)